# How to set our own custom theme in PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, primeng

I am using latest version of  `"primeng": "^12.2.0",`I want to set my own custom theme of primeng. I gone through many blogs, but couldn't find any solution.

I copied `theme.css` file from `‘node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-blue’` and made my new folder in src and I imported my new theme in `angular.json` file. But above theme.css file containing 6000+ lines of css code, and it doesn't following any variable, it means every css class containing color code, means that class color does not referring any single variable, so that if suppose I want to change `primary color` of theme, so I have to change only one variable.

Is there any better way to change the primary color, secondary color, etc in primeng?

Comment: They have removed the ability to create custom themes in PrimeNG a long time ago and  introduced a paid tool that allows you to do so - [Designer](https://www.primefaces.org/designer/primeng). One of many, many reasons why we decided to drop PrimeNG from all of our products and use other libraries.

Comment: @TotallyNewb you mean we can't set the our own custom theme?

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 4):

For what I understand of your problem, you want to factorize your CSS variables.

For the most part, it has been made really difficult to force you to buy a theme already made, or for you to buy the theme generator.

There is no easy way of doing it natively. You can arm yourself with patience and go with `CTRL + F` or pay the licence.

In my team, we went with the easy way. You will lose more time than buying the concrete theme, or the designer. It depends what is worth the pain you will go through.

[Link for the store](https://www.primefaces.org/store/)

[Link for the theme designer licence](https://www.primefaces.org/store/designer.xhtml)

Comment: Absurd. Paying to recreate your own companies theme is a ridiculous request.

Comment: Absurd or not, it is fact. It is their business model, and if you don't like it, don't pay it. But in this case I don't see much alternatives to respond to the question asked in this post